# NotesJSONNavigator experiencing severe issues when parsing packages with empty string values

Tags: lotusscript

I am using the new NotesJSONNavigator object to parse a response from a third-party API. The responses I am observing look well-formatted (JSON), but my code was spitting out some strange results.

I narrowed it down to JSON values that were represented by empty strings. In those cases, the 'value' retrieved from the JSON is unpredictable and random (system characters).

I prepared a sample test JSON package string and can reliably reproduce the results using the logic below...  am I missing something here?

```vb
response$ = |{"resultcode":200,"result":[{"id":41,"eMail Address":"test@abc.com"},{"id":57,"eMail Address":""}]}|

Set jsonNav = session.CreateJSONNavigator( response$ )
Set jsonEl = jsonNav.GetElementByName( "result" )
Set jsonArr = jsonEl.Value

Set listEl = jsonArr.GetFirstElement()
Do While Not( listEl Is Nothing )
    Set jsonObj = listEl.Value
    checkEmail = jsonObj.GetElementByName( "eMail Address" ).Value
    Set listEl = jsonArr.GetNextElement()       
Loop
```

As long as there is data in the "eMail Address" portion, everything parses fine. If that data is an empty string (as for ID 57 above), the checkEmail variable is set to some very strange characters and is NOT blank!

Comment: Thanks for reporting Terry, I can confirm this is an issue and have opened a defect DCONBB2KNR.